# Cohomology of $S$-arithmetic groups with trivial coefficients such as $H^n(\rm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/N]);\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, arithmetic-groups

As $\rm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})*(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$, its cohomology groups $H^n(\rm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z});\mathbb{Z})$ are easy to get.
Let $N$ be a product of distinct primes.
How about $H^n(\rm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/N]);\mathbb{Z})$
and $H^n(\rm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/N]);\mathbb{Z})$ ?

Any references will be helpful.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. There are many known vanishing theorems (for real coefficients, hence, proving finiteness of group cohomology with integer coefficients), there are also some nonvanishing theorems. Try to narrow down your question to something which does not require a survey paper and explain what you know beyond the $PSL(2,Z)$ case.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you! I have give two specific groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a hard problem in general. When $N$ is not prime, then even the first homology of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\frac{1}{N}])$ is non-trivial to compute (cf. Corollary 4.4 of [1]), but I recently did so; see [arXiv:2401.08146](https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.08146); see also [arXiv:2401.06330, Prop. 4.4](https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.06330) for an independent proof from the day before. This is always a finite group (indeed always a quotient of $\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z}$), and the exact answer depends only on $\gcd(N,6)$. In particular $H^1(\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\frac{1}{N}]), \mathbf{Z}) = 0$ for all $N$. This result appears already as Proposition 4.1 of [1].

For higher cohomology groups, some more is known, see [1], particularly Proposition 4.2. In the general case of $N = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$, all distinct prime factors, we have that for all $m \geq k+2$, the group $H^m(\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\frac{1}{N}]), \mathbf{Z})$ is a finite group with only $2$-torsion and $3$-torsion. So for any fixed $N$ the groups eventually always become finite.

Finally, for $N=p$ prime, the full cohomology is known. This is done in the paper [2], (on the arXiv as [arXiv:9503230](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9503230)) which a quick Google search discovers, given the title of the paper. As expected from the above, $H^m$ is finite for $m \geq 3$ (with only $2$- and $3$-torsion), but $H^2$ can have arbitrarily high torsion-free rank.

${}$

[1] *Williams, Frank; Wisner, Robert J.*, [**Cohomology of certain congruence subgroups of the modular group**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-98-04367-6), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 126, No. 5, 1331-1336 (1998). [ZBL0894.20034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0894.20034).

[2] *Adem, Alejandro; Naffah, Nadim*, [**On the cohomology of ($\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])$)**](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9503230), Kropholler, Peter H. (ed.) et al., Geometry and cohomology in group theory. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. Lond. Math. Soc. Lect. Note Ser. 252, 1-9 (1998). [ZBL0913.20033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0913.20033).

Comment: The statement "even the first homology of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[1/N])$ was an open problem"  is just false; it's an immediate consequence of the CSP for these groups due to Serre in 1970, which implies the homology is just $\bigoplus H_1(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p,\mathbf{Z})$ for the primes $p \in \{2,3\}$ which don't divide $N$. (And those terms for $p=2$ and $p=3$ were also known long before then as well.)

Comment: @user491858 Sure, if one knows that the first homology is finite then one can apply CSP as you say (although it’s certainly not required). But perhaps I am missing what your argument is for that the first homology is finite? And yes, for $p=2,3$ the answer was indeed well known.

Comment: @user491858 Nevertheless, using Corollary 4.4 of [1] it does follow that the abelianization is finite, but this is far from a trivial consequence of CSP (and if the abelianization were easy to compute, then surely the Corollary would not be phrased as partially as it is). Combining that with CSP does now give the formula — so I’ve weakened the phrasing a bit.

Comment: Assuming the group is finitely generated (which was also certainly known in 1970) then it absolutely is a trivial consequence of CSP that the homology is finite. Any map to $\mathbf{Z}$ gives a map to $\mathbf{Z}/n \mathbf{Z}$ for any $n$ which (for $n \ge 5$ prime) doesn't exist by CSP.

Answer (score 0):

I added this non-answer since it is too long for a comment.
EDIT: In the first version I claimed that the action is free, which it is not.

There is a very explicit model for the classifying space $EPGL_n(\mathbb{Z}[1/(N])$, namely the product of the space of inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the affine buildings for each prime in $N$.
One can verify that this space has a proper discontinouos group action with finite stabilizers and it is actually a model for $\underline{E}(G)$, the classifying space with respect to finite stabilizers.
The issue is that the discrete group $PGL_n(\mathbb{Z}[1/n])$ does not embed as a discrete group, thus the orbits are not discrete under the action on the space of inner products. The reason why this is possible is that there are arbitrarily large denominators allowed in $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$. The toy example of $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$ acting on $\mathbb{R}$ by translations is helpful. But luckily the affine buildings can help to fix exactly this problem. They have very large isotropy groups, but if denominators are really small, they move things far away. In sum the action on the product above has finite stabilizers and  is properly discontinuously.

Then the desired cohomology is the cohomology of the quotient. The is the canonical map $EG\to \underline{E}G$ which can be used to study the homology of the quotient, but usually one has to have a lot of input about the cohomology of the fibers, which needs knowledge about which finite subgroups arise in $G$.

Comment: The action on the product will be properly discontinuous but it cannot be free (because a finite nontrivial group cannot act freely on a contractible finite-dimensional CW complex). This makes things more complicated than you are describing.

Comment: Thanks. Of course you are right. It is a model for E_FIN(G) Let me correct this.